# What $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ really mean?

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image]

Hello. I have a question. I understand that, when $h\to0$, $r(h)\to0$ too. But why the author didn't wrote $r(h)\to0$ and wrote $\frac{r(h)}{h}\to0$. I know that $h\to0$ means that for smaller x values that $\to$ 0, we get smaller r(x) values that $\to$ 0, but what $\frac{r(h)}{h}\to0$ really means?

Comment: It means that $r(h)$ goes to zero even faster than $h$ does.

Comment: And you can explain me please how we get from (7) to (8) ? I don't understand very good. Thanks you!

Comment: (7) to (8) nothing much is happening. You're **defining** the function $r$ by fixing an $x$ and setting $r(h)=f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h$. Therefore, by rearrangement, $f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+r(h)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small $h$, we should have
$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$
This says that
$$
f'(x)h \approx f(x+h)-f(x).
$$
To turn the approximation into an equality, define the error term $r(h)$ so that
$$
f'(x)h +r(h) = f(x+h)-f(x).
$$
In short, $r(h)= f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h$. After division by $h$ and taking the limit as $h \to 0$ we must get $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{h}=0$ because the limit of the right-hand side
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h}{h}
$$
becomes
$f'(x)-f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Oops, you beat me to the exact same answer. I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really understand now!